# Print child category slug nicename

Tags: categories

I want to print (display) the child category slug, so I can use it in a dynamic url, on categories pages.
 So
 If I am on the category www.example.com/category/main-category/child-category
  Example: www.example.com/category/games/board-games

In the sidebar I will have a link Updates from Board Games
  so I need the code to simply display child-category slug, in this case is "board-games", and child category name, in this case is "Board Games"

on post pages it's simple, I have this code and it's working (maybe someone will find it useful)

```
<?php $cat_slug = get_the_category(); ?><a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url') . "/updates-from-" . $cat_slug[0]->category_nicename; ?>" > Updates from '<?php echo $cat_slug[0]->cat_name . "";?>'</a>
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: the question is what I want...and I don't know how to do it

Comment: is that hard to understand what the question is? "I want to print (display) the child category slug, so I can use it in a dynamic url, on categories pages"

Answer (score 0):

seems nobody understood 'my question', so I solved it myself here is the code for getting the slug I needed

```
<?php $cat = get_term_by('name', single_cat_title('',false), 'category'); echo $cat->slug; ?>
```